# how to get response of 2 api calls in angular js with $q.all and service

Tags: angularjs

i want to call 2 api and want to store the response in the scope variable. but im not able to get the data in the scope variable. im using $q.all and service for calling the api

error

> angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

```
 var app = angular.module('mymodule', []);

 app.service('doorService', function ($http) {
     this.get = function () {
         var response = $http.get("url");
         console.log(response);
         alert("test");
         return response;
     };
 });      

 app.service('waterService', function ($http) {
     this.get = function () {
         var response = $http.get("url");
         return response;
     };
 });
```

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $q, doorService, waterService) {

     $scope.DoorData = [];
     $scope.WatertankData = [];
     loadData();          

     function loadData() {
         var promiseDoor = doorService.get();
         var promiseWater = waterService.get();

         $scope.combineResult = $q.all([
                promiseDoor, 
                promiseWater 
         ]).then(function (resp) {
            $scope.DoorData= resp[0].data;
            $scope.WatertankData= resp[1].data;
         });
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadData() {
     var promises = [
          doorService.get(),
          waterService.get()
     ];
     $q.all(promises).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.DoorData= resp[0].data;
        $scope.WatertankData= resp[1].data;
        $scope.combineResult = {
            'DoorData': resp[0].data,
            'WatertankData':resp[1].data
        };
     });
 }
```